# Android HashMap<String, String> getValue from string key

Tags: java, android, hashmap, key-value

I have a tabhost that contains fragment tabs. Inside one of them I have a google map. All works fine, but when I touch one of the marker I have problems with the dialog content. The dialog that appears has the title with the `aCode` string, but no body. The `String mFromCode = (String)mMap.get(aCode);` code returns null to `mFromCode`, but if I change `aCode` with the value of aCode (for example "LIM") all works fine and `mFromCode` correctly has the value of the key-value pair.   What can I do to solve this problem?

```
map.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(
            new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener(){
                public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker){
                    String aCode = (String) marker.getSnippet().substring(0,marker.getSnippet().indexOf("-"));
                    String mFromCode = (String)mMap.get(aCode);
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                    builder1.setTitle(aCode);
                    builder1.setMessage(mFromCode);
                    builder1.setCancelable(true);
                    builder1.setPositiveButton("Ok",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });
                    AlertDialog alert11 = builder1.create();
                    alert11.show();

                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), mFromCode, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
            );
```

Comment: Before getting string to assing to mFromCode, check if that pair exist. If map doesn't have it, it will return null. Did you debug your code while you're getting error?

Comment: @mgokgoz Yes, I do. And that key-value pair exists. When I debug I see the aCode variable with value LIM, but hashmap value is null. If I change aCode with "LIM" it works fine.